# Terminar método after en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

He estado escribiendo unos cuantos programas para ejecutar un pase de diapositivas con Tkinter, y no he tenido inconvenientes ya que he visto diversas formas de utilizar el método after, pero mi curiosidad esta en como lo termino, ya que es un loop que puede estar ejecutándose hasta el fin de los tiempos, y pues me preguntaba como haría para terminarlo.

Aquí muestro algo del código con el que he estado practicando:

```
def times():
    global Timer1
    clock.config(text="imagen 0",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
    Timer1 = Timer1+1
    print(Timer1)

    if Timer1 > 5:
        clock.config(text="imagen1",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
          
    if Timer1 > 6:
        clock.config(text="imagen2",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
        
    if Timer1 > 9:
        clock.config(text="imagen3",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
        
    if Timer1 >= 10:
        Timer1 = 0
        clock.after(1000, times)
        
    else:
        clock.after(1000,times)
```

Luego que el contador llega a 10, reinicio la variable Timer1 y comienzo el conteo para que vuelva a iniciar las instrucciones de las imágenes, pero mi duda es: ¿Cómo se termina ese proceso que esta en ejecución?.

Espero que mi código les pueda ser de ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres que tu pregunta sea vista por más gente, te recomiendo agregar la etiqueta Python

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para corregir el formato del código. Sugiero que le des clic en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/445515/edit) para que te fijes como se hace. El editor tiene botones con la ayuda de markdown. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Ender! c:

## Como detener la ejecución de la función.

En este código hice un botón con el que se puede pausar y poner play al pase de diapositivas:

```
from tkinter import *

def times():
    global Timer1
    clock.config(text="imagen 0",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
    Timer1 = Timer1+1
    print(Timer1)

    if Timer1 > 5:
        clock.config(text="imagen1",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
          
    if Timer1 > 6:
        clock.config(text="imagen2",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
        
    if Timer1 > 9:
        clock.config(text="imagen3",bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
        
    if Timer1 >= 10:
        Timer1 = 0

    # esto se ejecuta sin importar la condición de arriba
    # por lo que no es necesario ponerlo dentro de un if/else
    # Si la variable play es True, la función times se llama en el proximo segundo

    if(play):
        clock.after(1000,times)

def toggle_play():
    global play
    
    if(play):
        play = False
    else:
        # Si la variable play vale False cuando se presiona el boton, play cambia a True
        # y se llama a la función times dentro del proximo segundo.
        play = True
        clock.after(1000,times)

clock = Label()
clock.pack()

Button(command=toggle_play).pack()

Timer1 = 0
play = True

times()
```

## Bonus: Unas palabras sobre optimización

Supongamos que Timer1 vale 8 y veamos que pasa si se ejecuta la función times.

1-Se establece la imagen0
2-Se le suma 1 a la variable Timer1
3-Se evalua la condición `Timer1 > 5` que da verdadero. Se establece la imagen1.
4-Se evalua la condicion `Timer1 > 6` que da verdadero. Se establece la imagen2.
5-Se evaluan las condiciones restantes, que dan falso.
6-Se ordena a Tkinter que ejecute la función times en el proximo segundo.

No crees que los pasos 1 y 3 son innecesarios? Para que vas a establecer la imagen0 y luego la 1 si tu intención es mostrar en pantalla la imagen2?
Sería mejor evitar esto y establecer la nueva imagen solo cuando sea el momento adecuado. Por ejemplo, que cuando `Timer1 == 6` se establesca la imagen2 nada más.

Entonces, habría que usar condiciones como `if(Timer1 == 6)`.

También es una buena costumbre usar elifs para que una vez que uno de los elifs de verdadero, no se evaluen los condicionales restantes.

Otro detalle que noto es que cada vez que cambias la imagen estableces nuevamente el fondo, la fuente y el color de la letra del Label. Si sin importar la imagen, el fondo, la fuente y el color de la letra es el mismo, puedes especificarselo una vez sola y listo.

Teniendo en cuenta todo esto, el código quedaría así:

```
from tkinter import *

def times():
    global Timer1
    Timer1 = Timer1+1
    print(Timer1)

    # Si Timer1 vale 1, entonces se ejecuta esta condicion y no se evalua el resto.
    if(Timer1 == 1):
        clock.config(text="imagen 0")

    elif Timer1 == 5:
        clock.config(text="imagen1")
          
    elif Timer1 == 6:
        clock.config(text="imagen2")
        
    elif Timer1 == 9:
        clock.config(text="imagen3")
        
    elif Timer1 >= 10:
        Timer1 = 0

    # esto se ejecuta sin importar la condición de arriba
    # por lo que no es necesario ponerlo dentro de un if/else
    # Si la variable play es True, la función times se llama en el proximo segundo

    if(play):
        clock.after(1000,times)

def toggle_play():
    global play
    
    if(play):
        play = False
    else:
        # Si la variable play vale False cuando se presiona el boton, play cambia a True
        # y se llama a la función times dentro del proximo segundo.
        play = True
        clock.after(1000,times)


# Creo el label y le establesco una vez sola el fondo, color de letra y fuente.
clock = Label(bg="white",fg="green",font="Arial 120 bold")
clock.pack()

Button(command=toggle_play).pack()

Timer1 = 0
play = True

times()
```

Answer (score 0):

Quien provoca la *repetición* eres tu mismo, al llamar a `clock.after(x, times)`, tu mismo le estás diciendo que vuelva a invocar `times()` después de x milisegundos. Si quieres detener el ciclo, simplemente, no llames a dicha función.

Obviamente, ya que hay ocasiones en las que quieres que continúe y alguna ocasión en la que quieres que se detenga, tienes que tener algún mecanismo de control externo a la función y, dentro de ella condicionarlo... mira este pequeño ejemplo:

```
control = 1

def times():
    global control
    control += 1    
    print("ejecución", control)
    if control < 10:
        clock.after(1000, times)

times()
```

Con la variable de `control`, ejecuto cierto número de veces.

El ejemplo es sencillo para que comprendas la esencia... ya en la práctica, la condición puede ser tan compleja como quieras, lo importante es que, en cada ejecución, tu mismo decides si quires que se vuelva a invocar el método o no. Cuando ya no quieres que se invoque, simplemente, ya no llamas a `clock.after()`.